# NSSM Python Service pausing due to module error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandasql, nssm

I am trying to run a simple python script using NSSM (Non Sucking Service Manager) but I am failing to do so.

**Error I am getting:**

> `Unexpected status SERVICE_PAUSED in response to START control`

**I checked the error log file and it says the following error:**

> `from pandasql import sqldf as query  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandasql'`

Pandasql is already installed and when I manually try to run the code, it is running smoothly.

Can anyone help to resolve this please?